# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, net-http

The code below yields the following error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A

```
require 'net/https'
uri = URI.parse("https://<server>.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.ssl_version = 'SSLv3'
http.get(uri.request_uri)
```

Any idea why? I tried everything mentioned in all other questions, still no luck.

- Ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
- OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

**Update I**

Tried the following:

- Ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
- OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014

**Update II**

- Forced ssl_version to :TLSv1_2

Still no luck.

**Update III**

Alright, here's the final code - thanks to Steffen (see answer below):

```
require 'net/https'
uri = URI.parse("https://<server>.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1
http.ciphers = ['RC4-SHA']
http.get(uri.request_uri)
```

I doubt that my question will be relevant to anyone else since it was related to a remote misconfigured server.

Comment: it was useful for me :)

Comment: Also on /r/asknetsec https://www.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/64ulgg/what_would_be_a_secure_ssl_configuration_for_the/

Comment: one reason could be simply a network disconnection. took me 5 hours to find out :|

Comment: What worked for me is to reduce the number of threads.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is a problem at the server site. It looks like the server is exclusively accepting TLS 1.2 and does not show the usual behavior when the client requests something lesser (like downgrading or sending SSL alert) but instead just closes the connection.

TLS 1.2 is not supported by OpenSSL 0.9.8 and additionally your code enforces SSLv3. You get TLS 1.2 only when upgrading to OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Some browsers will also fail to connect to this server, even if they have ways to work around such broken servers. But while Firefox will only try to downgrade the connection to lesser SSL version (which often helps) Chrome manages to connect with TLS 1.2.

Edit: I've analyzed the issue further and now I cannot get a connection with TLS1.2 anymore but I can get a connection with TLS1.0 or SSL3.0, but only if the ciphers is hard coded to RC4-SHA. I've tried others like AES128-SHA or DES-CBC3-SHA and they don't work.
So while it looks like a really messed up system explicitly setting

```
http.ssl_version = 'TLSv1'       -- or SSLv3, but TLSv1 is better
http.ssl_cipher = 'rc4-sha'
```

should work. I'm not a ruby user so the exact syntax might differ, but I've tested with OpenSSL s_client.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I updated the question above with more info based on your feedback.

Comment: See edit - looks like you can succeed by forcing RC4-SHA as cipher.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks so much for your help! Here's what I did: `http.ssl_version = :TLSv1` and `http.ciphers = ['RC4-SHA']`. Thanks again!

Comment: where do I put this?

Comment: where do I put this? I'm also facing same issue using ruby2.5 and openssl version 1.0.2

Comment: @Hesham where do i put this `http.ssl_version = :TLSv1` and `http.ciphers = ['RC4-SHA']`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to upgrade to openssl `1.0.2g-1​ubuntu4.6` (from `1.0.1f-1​ubuntu2.21`) (e.g. from `cedar-14` to `heroku-16` stack).

```
heroku stack:set heroku-16 -a your-app
```

And in `app.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "stack": "heroku-16",
  ...
}
```

Comment: Now I get `SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A` less often, but still happens

Comment: Same issue with me

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the problem was the MTU size!

Comment: How did you fix that?