# SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A with Ruby RESTful client

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now. I am trying to use Rest-Client ruby gem to hit an API endpoint using SSL certs. I know for sure that the server is responding only to TLSv_1_2 and TLSv_1_1, however I can't seem to be able to make it work.
This is the snippet of the code:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new(
                endpoint,
                :ssl_client_cert  => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(config["cert"])),
                :ssl_client_key   =>  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(config["key"])),
                :ssl_version      => :TLSv1_2,
                :verify_mode      =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
            )

response = resource.delete(:params => {:name => 'test'})

p endpoint + " | " + response.code.to_s
```

That's what I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:413:in `transmit'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:176:in `execute'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient
from test.rb:47:in `<main>'
```

I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814210/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv3-read) for a while, but it hasn't helped much.

Comment: Have you tried using the regular `net/http` stdlib? I would try to get that working and then switch it to Rest-Client.

Comment: Yes I did, same result unfortunately :(

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

A top level initializer is highly recommended to use:

**conf/initializer/tls_settings.rb**

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ssl_version] = 'TLSv1_2'
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I am not using Rails though. Is that still relevant?

Comment: Yes, it is about settings for Ruby stdlib