# How do I retrive a certificate and view it's subject in Ruby 1.9.3 with OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, openssl, ssl-certificate

In Bash I'd just:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | grep 'subject'
```

But I want to do it elegantly in ruby.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are trying to do with the built-in [OpenSSL Ruby module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html).

Specifically you can use the [SSLSocket](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLSocket.html) class to retrieve the certificate as a [X509:Certificate](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html) object, which has an accessor for subject.

The example code found [here](http://findingscience.com/ruby/ssl/2013/01/13/reading-an-ssl-cert-in-ruby.html) is very close to what you are trying to do.

Comment: This works great! unless the server is using unsupported TLS versions, but that's another matter, discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814210/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv3-read