# Ruby and SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3

Tags: ruby, windows, openssl

Facing this error on windows working fine on ubuntu  tried many soltuions but nothing is working for me .please do not mark this as dublicate .

```
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.10.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:83:in `perform_request'
    from C:/Ruby22x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday0.10.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:41:in `block in call'
    from C:/Ruby_22x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday0.10.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:88:in `with_net_http_connection'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.10.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:33:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.10.0/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.10.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.10.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.10.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:177:in `post'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/signet-0.7.3/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:960:in `fetch_access_token'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/signet-0.7.3/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:998:in `fetch_access_token!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/googleauth-0.5.1/lib/googleauth/signet.rb:69:in `fetch_access_token!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/googleauth-0.5.1/lib/googleauth/signet.rb:45:in `apply!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.20/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:300:in `apply_request_options'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.20/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:282:in `block in execute_once'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/hurley-0.2/lib/hurley/client.rb:46:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.20/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:272:in `execute_once'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.20/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:107:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib/retriable.rb:53:in `block in retriable'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `with_index'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `retriable'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.20/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:104:in `block in execute'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib/retriable.rb:53:in `block in retriable'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `with_index'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/retriable-2.0.2/lib/retriable.rb:48:in `retriable'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.20/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:96:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.20/lib/google/apis/core/base_service.rb:351:in `execute_or_queue_command'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google-api-client-0.9.20/generated/google/apis/drive_v3/service.rb:772:in `get_file'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google_drive-2.1.2/lib/google_drive/session.rb:216:in `file_by_id'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google_drive-2.1.2/lib/google_drive/session.rb:228:in `file_by_url'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/google_drive-2.1.2/lib/google_drive/session.rb:275:in `spreadsheet_by_url'from final_gmail_script.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

code sample

```
require 'capybara'
require 'google_drive'
require 'headless'
require 'certified'

credentials = Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials.new(
 client_id: "15##########3-k###################################hu2e.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 client_secret: "r#####_TO-#######3_E-##-",
 scope: [
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
   "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/",
 ],
 refresh_token: "1/BYLI########################################4")
 google_session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_credentials(credentials)
 google_spreadsheet = google_session.spreadsheet_by_url("#########")
```

getting error while trying get spreadsheet_by_url.

ruby version is - 2.2.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814210/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv3-read ?

Comment: Use TLS 1.0 (or above) and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Also see [ruby "SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3"](https://www.google.com/search?num=40&q=ruby+"SSL_connect+SYSCALL+returned%3D5+errno%3D0+state%3DSSLv2%2Fv3"&oq=ruby+"SSL_connect+SYSCALL+returned%3D5")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are not sending the certificate to access the spreadsheet. You probably need to generate one through Google Services, export it, give your spreadsheet access to your google services email user and then use the certificate to make the request.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard for more info

Comment: Hey @xenover thanks for your response but i am using the  config.json file provided by google for accessing the spreadsheets and the script is working fine on ubuntu but it is throwing the particular error on windows