# Error: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, centos

I getting the following error on Rails 2.2.4 and openssl 1.0.2 on CentOS

```
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

backtrace:

"/opt/issues_service/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'",
"/opt/issues_service/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'",
"/opt/issues_service/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'",
"/opt/issues_service/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'",
"/opt/issues_service/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/httplog-0.3.2/lib/httplog/adapters/net_http.rb:38:in `connect'",
"/opt/issues_service/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'",
"/opt/issues_service/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'",
"/opt/issues_service/ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'",
...
```

Any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814210/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-syscall-returned-5-errno-0-state-sslv3-read is this of help?

Comment: can you please check once to make sure that your SSL certificate is recently updated or not. This might occur because of certification expiration.

Comment: We check the certificate and it is fine. We running `openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq` we get: `SSLv3` and `TLSv1.2`